# Problem with method call, especially calling Assembly From C

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, nasm

I'm trying to write a small OS, but am having a problem when I call my assembly function from C.

```
[BITS 16]
extern init

call   init

mov    SI, msg
call   printstr
call   printstr

jmp    $

global printstr
printstr:
 mov    AL, [SI]
 inc    SI

 cmp    AL, 0
 je     end
 call   printchar
 jmp    printstr

printchar:
 mov    BL, 10
 mov    AH, 0x0E;Opcode ein Zeichen auszugeben
 mov    BH, 0x00;Seite
 int    0x10
 ret

end:
 ret

msg     db 'bla', 0
```

`void init` is definitely called because when I create an endless while loop into my `void init`, my "bla" message won't be send.

If I call `printstr` method twice in my assembly code, the output changes and it does not depend on the cursor.
[image]

The problem is now, when I try to call `printstr` from my C method, nothing happens, not even the message I send with my assembly code after `init` is called.

```
extern printstr();

void init() {
  printstr();
}
```

As soon as I try to call the `printstr` function from C nothing works.
[image]

The assembly program was compiled with NASM on Linux and the C part with GCC and the output format is elf32-i386.

I hope anybody can help me.

Comment: gcc creates 32-bit code, but your assembly seems to be 16-bit code.  I don't see how this has any chance of working.

Comment: Also `printstr` expects `si` to be set up which your C code doesn't do.

Comment: You might want to try [ia16-gcc](https://github.com/tkchia/build-ia16) or some other 16 bit compiler to generate 16 bit code.